# How to remove Datastream UUID from BigQuery tables during MySQL CDC replication?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-datastream

I'm using Datastream to replicate data from MySQL to BigQuery, but I want to exclude the Datastream UUID column that's added to my BigQuery tables. However, I still need to maintain CDC (Change Data Capture) functionality. How can I achieve this?

Here's a breakdown of my setup:

- I'm using Datastream to replicate data from MySQL to BigQuery.
- Datastream automatically adds a UUID column to the replicated tables in BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @Deepak Singh Rajput, I have posted one workaround as an answer, if it helps you can consider accepting or upvoting. Before creating a view just take a look at the [materialized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro) also.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/events-and-streams), metadata fields are automatically included when an event is generated. With Datastream, you can specify include and exclude lists for tables and schemas, to stream only the data that you want from a source to a destination. For included tables, you can exclude specific columns of the tables to further fine-tune exactly which data you want to be streamed into the destination.

Based on my understanding we cannot turn off creating  metadata fields columns in the BigQuery. As a workaround you can consider creating a  [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) including only the column you wanted from the bigquery table created by the datastream. If you want this feature in datastream  you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).